# Overriding CKEditor CSS in Angular2

Tags: css, angular, ckeditor

I want to override the css style of the CKEditor. If I just put my CSS in my own CSS file, my custom css is overridden by the default css style of CKEditor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load your own CSS file after the CSS file of CKEditor and ensure the CSS selectors have higher selectivity.

Comment: `!important` should be used as last resort. There are other means to increase selectivity without `!import`. Like duplicating a selector like `div.some-class.some-class { ... }`

Comment: If I just load my CSS file after the CSS file of CKEditor and duplicate the selector without using `!import`, my css is ignored

Comment: If the CKEditor selector uses an ID selector or they are using inline styles you'll have a hard time getting a higher specifity. It's hard to give concrete advice without more information. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/.

Comment: Yes you are right the CKEditor is using ID selectors

Comment: I haven't tried myself yet but I think you can also repeat the id like `#id#id.some-class {}`

Comment: Repeating the id works, but is it not easier to use `!important` instead of repeating the id?

Comment: With duplicate ids you still have the opportunity to use triple-ids or `!important` for example for debugging purposes. With `!important` all workarounds are closed. Imagine CKEditor had used `!important` In the end it's up to you if you use `!important` or not and if this can cause any harm to yourself or anybody using your code. It's just generally considered bad practice and you should be aware of the downsides if you use it.

Comment: "Load your own CSS file "- how?

Comment: Add a `<style>...</style>` tag with your css orl loead it from a file using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`